Share script on the same time
my issue is that I'm working in a course in university called digital tools and we have a group project. Therefore we work on an assignment as a group and we have to prepare certain scripts for it. We are 3 people in this group  and we want to work on the script on the same time. We already shared the script as a linked folder to our sharepoint, but unfortunately it takes a lot of time to update it when somebody worked on it, so I wanted to know if there is any way to work on the same script at the exactly same time.
Thanks in advance!
We tried to connect us with our university sharepoint as a shared folder.
